# Conflict on a transition on jquery .load

Tags: jquery

Hello friends I have this code in my index:

```
<script>
$(".myLink").click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#container').load(href);
  $('#container').fadeTo( 500, 1);
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "normal");
  return false;
});
</script>
```

It works excelente.
Next, when the #container opens and itsc content loaded, I need to close it, so I use the following code inside the #container window:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
  $('#container').fadeTo( 500, 0 );
  var href = $('cont_nota').attr('href');
  $("#container").empty();
  $(this).unbind( fadeTo );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Again everything OK, when I click any where in the window it closes the #container (as expected), except it doesn't fade out, it closes abruptly, I can live with that, but where I'm really struggling with is: when I try to open a new link from within the #container. It loads the new content into itself (the #container windows) like expected but now it doesn't fade in, it appears abruptly.

This is the code I use to load new content into the same container:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#container").html("");
  $('#container').load(href);
  $('#container').fadeTo( 500, 1);
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "normal");
  return false;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Any idea of what may be wrong?
Thanks for any insight.

Comment: In your close function you set `href`, but never use it. And you use a variable `fadeTo` that you never set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JS is working `asynchronously`, `fadeTo` function does not block the execution of other lines. Therefore, after the execution of first line, your code *immediately* starts executing other lines *not after* `fadeTo` method finishes.

Thus, if you want to wait to finish fading, you should write your code in a callback function. Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) for the usage of `fadeTo` function with a callback.

So your function chain should look like:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
  $('#container').fadeTo( 500, 0, function() {
      var href = $('cont_nota').attr('href');
      $("#container").empty().css('opacity','100');
      $(this).unbind( fadeTo );
      event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, Thank's Batuhan, but now when it closes the container, and I click another links open an empty window... I'm guessing the next time I click a link it opens the container but with 0 opacity.

I removed the $(this).unbind( fadeTo ); but still noting appears

Comment: Then after the fading in, since you are removing content, you can set the opacity back. See the edit please.

Comment: Ok... Thank you, your example is excellent, the only thing I had to do was to remove the $(this).unbind( fadeTo ); because it was disabling the function for next time use. :) this is how it ended Up: `code`
    $("#cont_nota").click(function(){
    $('#cont_nota').fadeTo( 500, 0, function(){
    $("#cont_nota").empty();
    });
    });

Comment: Found my problem. on the Div to be closed I replaced the fadeTo() for a fadeOut('slow') and that way I don't get any errors and everything fades in and out perfectly. I however left the fadeTo() on the parent document because don't now why if I use fadeIn() everything loads but content is invisible. Thanks for your help. :)